# Porque cuando selecciono un componente se activan otros? (JCheckBox / JRadioButton)

Tags: java

Estoy realizando un programa, donde la aplicación solicita nombre y apellido del usuario, y posteriormente , al hacer clic en los diversos componentes que están en el código (`JButton`, `JRadioButton`, `JCheckBox`), el resultado de las operaciones realizadas  se almacenan y setean en un `JTextArea`.

Sin embargo, hay algo ilógico que esta sucediendo, ya que cuando hago clic en los componentes `box2`, `radio1`y `radio2` el método no los tiene en cuenta, y sólo llama a la variable box1.

Me resulta un tanto extraño, porque no puedo detectar el error. 
Gracias de antemano!

Gonzalo

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Historico {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Marco miMarco=new Marco();
        miMarco.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        miMarco.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class Marco extends JFrame{
  public Marco() {
    setBounds(1000,200,700,500);
    setTitle("Historial");
    Lamina miLamina=new Lamina();
    add(miLamina);
  }
}

class Lamina extends JPanel{
  public Lamina() {             
    //SUPERIOR
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    superior=new JPanel();
    superior.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    etiqueta1=new JLabel("Nombre");
    etiqueta2=new JLabel("Apellido");
    texto1=new JTextField(20);
    texto2=new JTextField(20);
    superior.add(etiqueta1);
    superior.add(texto1);
    superior.add(etiqueta2);
    superior.add(texto2);
    add(superior,BorderLayout.NORTH);

    //CENTRO
    centro=new JPanel();
    centro.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    area=new JTextArea(15,40);
    area.setLineWrap(true);
    scroll=new JScrollPane(area);
    centro.add(scroll);
    add(centro,BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //INFERIOR
    inferior=new JPanel();
    inferior.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    boton1=new JButton("Boton 1");
    boton2=new JButton("Boton 2");
    box1=new JCheckBox("Casilla 1", true);          
    box2=new JCheckBox("Casilla 2");            
    radio1=new JRadioButton("Radio 1");
    radio2=new JRadioButton("Radio 2");
    grupo=new ButtonGroup();
    grupo.add(radio1);
    grupo.add(radio2);
    inferior.add(boton1);
    inferior.add(boton2);
    inferior.add(box1);
    inferior.add(box2);
    inferior.add(radio1);
    inferior.add(radio2);
    add(inferior,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    boton1.addActionListener(new Action());
    boton2.addActionListener(new Action());
    box1.addActionListener(new Action());
    box2.addActionListener(new Action());
    radio1.addActionListener(new Action());
    radio2.addActionListener(new Action());
}

private class Action implements ActionListener{
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(contador==1) {
      area.setText(texto1.getText() + " " + texto2.getText() + " ha realizado las siguientes operaciones");
      entrada=area.getText();               
      contador++;
    }

    if(e.getSource()==boton1) {             
      area.setText(entrada + "\n" + "El Boton 1 ha sido presionado");
      entrada=area.getText();               
    } else if(e.getSource()==boton2) {
      area.setText(entrada + "\n" + "El Boton 2 ha sido presionado");
      entrada=area.getText();   
    } else if(box1.isSelected()) {
      area.setText(entrada + "\n" + "Casilla 1 Activada");
      entrada=area.getText();   
    } else if(!box1.isSelected()) {
      area.setText(entrada + "\n" + "Casilla 1 Desactivada");
      entrada=area.getText();   
    }
  }
}

  private String entrada;
  private int contador=1;
  private ButtonGroup grupo;
  private JRadioButton radio1, radio2;
  private JButton boton1, boton2;
  private JCheckBox box1, box2;
  private JPanel superior,centro, inferior;
  private JTextArea area;
  private JTextField texto1,texto2;
  private JLabel etiqueta1,etiqueta2;
  private JScrollPane scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los objetos **box2**, **radio1** y **radio2** estan siguiendo la siguiente logica:

1. Cuando tu pulsas sobre alguno de ellos cambian su estado, esto visualmente lo puedes comprobar pues como lo mencionas al pulsar sobre box2 se selecciona o deselecciona y en el caso de radio1 y radio2 se seleccionan siguiendo la lógica de cualquier par de radios mutuamente excluyentes.
2. El método **actionPerformed** de todo componente es invocado por Java-Swing luego de que se cambia el estado del componente sobre el cual se actuó, **nunca antes**.
3. Si se ejecuta tu programa se verá una salida que siempre indica algo como:

> ```
> Casilla 1 Activada
> Casilla 1 Desactivada
> ```

Estos mensajes solo indican el estado de **box1** luego de que se ejecuto la acción sobre un componente.

Es decir tu código indica:
- Si el que pulso es el botón 1 entonces escribe "El boton 1 ha sido presionado" si no verifica si el botón 2 fue presionado, si lo fue escribe "El botón 2 ha sido presionado" si no indicame como esta box1 (Seleccionado o Deseleccionado).

Luego entonces si se pulsa sobre **radio1**, **radio2**, **box1** o **box2** el código solo agrega como esta **box1** (seleccionado o deseleccionado) a la salida que ya se tenía.

Ahora bien. Atendiendo a la funcionalidad que necesitas:

Como lo que quieres es que al pulsar en un botón/check/radio se agregue la acción del componente que se ha pulsado al **JTextArea** lo que se puede hacer es colocar los ifs parecido a como lo tienes pero sin anidarlos.

Una primer primer aproximación a lo que necesitas sería algo así como:

Si el que origina la accion es el componente x entonces vemos su estado y con esta información escribimos en la pantalla.

```
private class Action implements ActionListener{
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String mensaje = null;

// TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(contador==1) {
          area.setText(texto1.getText() + " " + texto2.getText() + " ha realizado las siguientes operaciones");
          entrada=area.getText();               
          contador++;
        }


        if( box1 == e.getSource() )
        {
           mensaje = "Casilla 1 ";

           if( box1.isSelected())
           {
          mensaje += " Activada.";
           }else
           {
          mensaje += " Desactivada";
           }

        }

        if( box2 == e.getSource() )
        {
           mensaje = "Casilla 2 ";

           if( box2.isSelected())
           {
          mensaje += " Activada.";
           }else
           {
          mensaje += " Desactivada";
           }       
        }

        if( radio1 == e.getSource())
        {
           mensaje = " Radio 1 ";
           if( radio1.isSelected())
           {
          mensaje += " Activado";
           }
           else{
          mensaje += " Desactivado";
           }
        }
        if( radio2 == e.getSource())
        {
           mensaje = " Radio 2 ";
           if( radio2.isSelected())
           {
          mensaje += " Activado";
           }
           else{
          mensaje += " Desactivado";
           }
        }

        if( boton1 == e.getSource() )
        {
           mensaje = "El Boton 1 ha sido presionado";
        }

        if ( boton2 == e.getSource() )
        {
           mensaje = "El Botón 2 ha sido presionado";
        }


        area.setText(entrada + "\n" + mensaje);
        entrada=area.getText();      

      }
    }
```

Lo que nos da una ejecución como la siguiente:

[image: Primer implementación]

Ahora esta solución grita que puede ser mejorada debido a que parece que estamos escribiendo una plana. Los primeros ifs se ven iguales salvo por el nombre de la variable y por el mensaje que estamos emitiendo. Una solución más limpia sería aprovechar que ya haz puesto el nombre del componente al momento de crear los **JCheckBox**, los **JRadioButton** y los **JButton**. Estas tres clases heredan de la clase **AbstractButton** y es en esta clase donde fue definido el método **getText** que nos sirve para recuperar el nombre que haz asignado al crear los componentes.

Por otro lado tanto **JRadioButton** como **JCheckBox** son clases que también heredan de la clase **JToggleButton**. De hecho el método **isSelected** esta definido en la clase **JToggleButton**.

Aprovechando estas circunstancias la clase Action ahora puede ser implementada así:

```
private class Action implements ActionListener{

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // se inicializa el mensaje con el nombre del elemento    
     AbstractButton componente = (AbstractButton)e.getSource();

     String mensaje = componente.getText();


   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(contador==1) {
      area.setText(texto1.getText() + " " + texto2.getText() + " ha realizado las siguientes operaciones");
      entrada=area.getText();               
      contador++;
    }

    // si es un check box o un radio boton
    if(  e.getSource() instanceof JToggleButton)
    {
       JToggleButton boxORadio = (JToggleButton)e.getSource();

       // si esta seleccionado
       if( boxORadio.isSelected() )
       {
      mensaje += " esta seleccionado";
       }
       else
       {
      mensaje += " esta deseleccionado";
       }

    }

    if( e.getSource() instanceof JButton)
    {
       mensaje = "El boton "+componente.getText()+" fue presionado";
    }

    area.setText(entrada + "\n" + mensaje);
    entrada=area.getText();      

  }
}
```

Esto nos da la siguiente salida:

[image: optimizado]

Te pido que me corrobores que esto que he añadido te sirva.
Si tienes alguna duda coloca otro comentario por favor.
Si lo que te he colocado te sirve favor de ponerme una palomita.

Comment: Hola @Alvaro, muchas gracias por tu comentario, entonces como podria solucionarlo? Quizas no comprendi muy bien tu respuesta! Saludos!

Comment: Hola Gonzalo. Pues exactamente no se cual es el efecto que deseas. ¿que quieres que pase cuando se pulsa box1? ¿que quieres que pase cuando se pulsa box2? ¿que quieres que pase cuando se pulsa radio2? Si agregas a tu pregunta que es exactamente lo que quieres ver cuando se pulse en estos botones/radios edito mi respuesta para mostrarte como lograrlo.

Comment: Hola @Alvaro! ahí edite mi post y aclare el objetivo y lo que me sucede. Básicamente es una aplicación que "memoriza" las operaciones realizadas por el usuario, ya se un clic en un botón, la activación de una casilla o de un JCheckRadio. Gracias!!!

Comment: Excelente Alvaro! Todo mas que claro. Muy amable por tu aporte :)